# Как поменять кодировку и прописать адрес

Tags: php

Я новичок в PHP и пытаюсь создать форму для отправки на почту электр.письма. Письма отправляет, но только русские буквы Yndex-почта выводит полной белебердой  РђСЂС‚СѓСЂ. Как поменять кодировку, у меня кодировка CP1251, я так думаю что надо utf-8? И еще в Yndex- почте в поле где отображает кто прислал письмо стоит NO adress, как это можно исправить? И если ты прописываешь email-адрес в форме, то yndex кидает письмо в спам, а то может и через минут десять в спам прислать,  а если без email-адреса отправляешь,  то присылает  тут же во входящие. В чем причина? Помогите разобраться?

**пример html:**

```
<div id="botton">
 <a href="#contactForm" class="botton-font">Запись Автосервис</a> 
</div>
<form id="contactForm" action="/catalog/processForm.php" method="post">

<h2>Шлите нам весточку</h2>
<ul>
<li>
  <label for="senderName">Ваше Имя</label>
  <input type="text" name="senderName" id="senderName" class="sender" placeholder="Пожалуйста введите свое имя" required="required" maxlength="40" />
</li>

<li>
  <label for="senderEmail">Ваш электронный адрес</label>
  <input type="email" name="senderEmail" id="senderEmail" class="sender" placeholder="Пожалуйста введите свой электронный адрес"  maxlength="50" />
</li>

 <li>
  <label for="phone">Ваш телефон</label>
  <input type="number" name="phone" id="phone" class="sender" placeholder="Пожалуйста введите свой телефон" required="required" maxlength="20" />
</li>

<li>
  <label for="marka">Марка и Модель А/М</label>
  <input type="text" name="marka" id="marka" class="sender" placeholder="Пожалуйста введите марку и модель авто" required="required" maxlength="200" />
</li>

<li>
  <label for="message" style="padding-top: .5em;">Что сделать?</label>
  <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Введите свою информацию о том что надо сделать" required="required" cols="80" rows="10" maxlength="10000"></textarea>
</li>
</ul>
<div id="formButtons">
<input type="submit" id="sendMessage" name="sendMessage" value="Отправить" />
<input type="button" id="cancel" name="cancel" value="Отменить" />
</div>
</form>
```

**пример php:**

```
<?php
$sender_Name = $_POST['senderName'];
$sender_Email = $_POST['senderEmail'];
$phone_namber = $_POST['phone'];
$marka_avto = $_POST['marka'];
$message_email = $_POST['message'];

$to = 'Avtoclub-mir@art.ru';
$subject = 'test';
$msg = "$sender_Name электронная почта $sender_Email.\n" .
"Номер телефона: $phone_namber\n" .
"Марка Автомабиля: $marka_avto\n" .
"Что надо сделать: $message_email\n";

mail($to, $subject, $msg, 'From:' . $email);

?>
```

Comment: tarantul помогло!!!!!!!!!!! Я сделал так:  
        $headers= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
        $headers .= "From:".$email."\n\r";
        mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers); Стало отоброжат по русски. Но появилась другая проблема, теперь другие слова "Номер телефона","Марка Автомабиля" и т.д. отображаются знаком ? пример:"????? ??????????: $marka_avto\n". Что можно сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для смены кодировки используйте функцию php  iconv - [php.net iconv](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.iconv.php)

Для указания адреса отправителя у Вас в четвёртом аргументе в примере не назначена переменная $email.

Для практики и повышения знаний рекомендую открыть письмо в bat-е например и посмотрите исходник и все заголовки(Header). Если какой либо из заголовков Вам будет непонятен, мучайте гугл, он подскажет :-)

Comment: Интересно! К стати я со спамом разобрался! Теперь пытаюсь с этой кодировкой разобраться, как вы думаете как и где мне можно использовать в моем php-сценарии переменную $string и вообще стоит ли ее использовать.  $string = iconv('cp1251', 'utf-8', $string); Что скажите?

Comment: перед командой отправки:
$msg = iconv('cp1251', 'utf-8', $msg);
mail($to, $subject, $msg, 'From:' . $email);

Comment: Я прописал но ситуация не меняется. Может проблема с yndex-почтой?

Comment: Добавьте в header принудительное указание кодировки письма utf-8: 
$header = "From:".$email."\n\r";
$header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n\r"
mail($to, $subject, $msg, $header);

Comment: Да что такое! Он не в какую не хочет отображать! Может я не так прописываю?  $header = "From:".$email."\n\r";
 $header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n\r"; 
     mail($to, $subject, $msg, $header); terantul посмотри, может я ошибки допустил?

Comment: Теперь в письме он еще и прописывает 
Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8.

Comment: $marka_avto = iconv('cp1251', 'utf-8', $marka_avto);  и так со всем что собираетесь отправлять.